# Cannot access a Iframe elements from other Iframe on a page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I have problems with `Iframes` in `Chrome`. I have 3 Iframes in a page. I am trying to access elements of one Iframe from another.

I am using with this code:

```
navFrame = window.parent.frames[0];
lnkTags = navFrame.document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

I am getting the following **error**: Cannot call method `'getElementsByTagName'` of undefined

I read in forums that `window.parent` will not work in chrome. Is it possible to do this differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `contentWindow` property like so:

```
navFrame = window.parent.frames[0];
lnkTags = navFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Comment: I get the following error if I use contentWindow property:   navFrame = window.parent.frames[0].contentWindow;
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///C:/Program%20Files/HNet/Publications/Title.htm# from frame with URL file:///C:/Program%20Files/HNet/Publications/Hyper.Net_Features_-_doc_d4779823/topics/4.1_Fonts/breadcrumb.htm. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: That's another problem. please read about `cross domain scripting`. in your case you can solve this easily by running your website from `localhost` instead of `file://...`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I need to have it working both from local computer and localhost. It is working from localhost but not from local computer. I have always contentWindow is undefined for the Iframe in Chrome. Is there any specific properties for chrome to get the document object of Iframe.

Comment: See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289063/how-to-bypass-document-domain-limitations-when-opening-local-files

Comment: For Google Chrome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy